# How To Auto Restart Dropwizard Application After Saving Changes In File

Tags: java, dropwizard, jrebel, spring-boot-devtools

In Spring boot Whenever files change in the classpath, applications using spring-boot-devtools will cause the application to restart. Some can be also be acheived using the JRebel, But JRebel is not Free.

I am looking for the same functionality in the dropwizard. Is there any free tool or any Library like devtools in Springboot that makes it possible in dropwizard?

Answer (score 0):

You could give  [HotSwapAgent](http://hotswapagent.org/index.html) a try. Should work with DropWizard.

Comment: Sure I will look into it very soon.